# Set different row table color basis on performance

Tags: php, sql

I am making  student performance records in SQL. There are only 2 columns.

```
sl no. Name    Points
1      Admam    89
2      Russel   86
3      Andy     79
4      Lance    76
5      Steve    75
6      jack     74
7      Phil     70
8      mark     67
9      kevin    65
10     andrew   65
11     brian    64
12     pat      63
```

This is SQL report format.. I need to colorize the table for every 3 students..For the first 3 student(1, 2, 3) called as 'Diamond' So that 3 rows needs to color Grey. Next 3 students (4,5,6) called as "platinum" so that 3 rows need to color green.

But in the next row, Phi, Mark, Kevin needs to color as Yellow. But Andrew also  joining with Kevin because for same points. So now 4 rows should be colorize as yellow.. Please let me know how to do that....

Comment: give every point a color code and apply style

Comment: [Arithmetic Functions in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html) - Specifically, the Modulo operator should work here.

Answer (score 0):

look at this fiddle [phpfiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FLCkzA)

```
     <?php
        $points=array(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3);
        $color= array(1=>'red',2=>'green',3=>'yellow');
    ?>

        <table width="100%">
            <?php
        foreach($points as $key=>$grade)
        {?>
        <tr>
        <td style="color:<?php if( $key!=0 &&  $points[$key]!=$points[$key-1] )
        {echo $color[$grade];} else{ if(($key+1)%3==0)
{ echo $color[$grade];} else {echo $color[$grade];} } ?>">
student <?php echo $key;  ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Ya correct. but there is one issue.. if u see the sl no. 7, 8, 9, points are different. Wat if the points are same? sl no. 9 and sl no. 10 are same points.. hence it should come same grade and it become 4 rows.. how do we calculate dat

Comment: both 9 and 10 must get the same color isn't it?

Comment: ya same color. but every 3 row color should be changed. Hence, 10, 11, 12 is diffrent color as per my report. but here the thing is 9 and 10 are same points so. 7,8,9,10 same color.

Comment: @ganesh jogii check now with slight changes you can use it.

Comment: It shows error to me. I m getting name and points from SQL database. Can u give further coding ....

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I-ze79yq_M3hW-KPehh1g3C1ZCK8HVc87uUPGsOa-3o/edit

Comment: pls check the above link... i need similar like this

Answer (score 0):

use a color for each range point like this

```
$colors = array(
    1 => 'grey',
    2 => 'green',
    3 => 'yellow',
    4 => 'black'
);
$i = 0;
$color_id = 0;
$lastpoint = -1;
foreach($students as $id=>$student) {
   $color_id += ($i % 3 == 0 && $student['point'] != $lastpoint) ? 1 : 0;
   $lastpoint = $student['point'];
?>
<tr>
    <td style="color:<?php echo colors[$color_id];?>";>
        <?php echo $student['name']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

Comment: There is no specific point to order by color.. but if points are same then it should take as a group...

Comment: There is no specific point to order by color.. but if points are same then it should take as a group.. I mean m not put condition for points. points can be anything.. no matter.. but foor every 3 rows color should change and if there r same points on a row, it should group.